# Pulling the first featured image from a custom post type post that is in a custom taxonomy

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to create a 'categories' page which displays all of my categories along with an image for that category. Instead of this page being static I want to pull through the most recent posts featured image for that category and use that as the category image.

My code below kind of works, it pulls through the most recent featured image but it doesn't appear to be category specific (it's just pulling through the most recent.

Just to clarify I am using a custom post type and a custom taxonomy:

Post Type: gallery
Taxonomy: categories

```
    <?php
    $limit      = 999;
    $counter    = 0;
    $cats = get_terms([
        'taxonomy' => 'categories',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    ]);

    foreach ($cats as $cat):
        if ($counter < $limit) {
            $args  = array(
                'posts_per_page' => 1,
                'post_type'   => 'gallery',
                'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                'cat' => $cat->cat_ID,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
            );
            $posts = get_posts($args);
            if ($posts) {
                    echo '<div class="col-md-3 category-list">';
                    while( have_posts() ) : the_post();
                    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '" ' . '><div class="cat-list-img">';
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    echo '<h5 class="cl-title">' . $cat->name . '</h5>';
                    echo '</div></a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                    endwhile;
            }
        }

    $counter++;
    endforeach;
    ?>
```

Since some of the posts share the same category, it would be great if I could avoid each using the same post and instead take the image from the next post (rather than duplicating), but I'm not sure how to do this so haven't even attempted - if it's easier than it sounds it would be great if you could also point me in the right direction for this.

Comment: `the_post_thumbnail` relies on the global post id. Use `get_the_post_thumbnail` instead, that takes the post ID as first parameter. (The latter does not output the result, but only returns it, so you'll have to `echo` it yourself.)

Comment: Or call `setup_postdata` first in your loop, then `the_post_thumbnail` might also work.

Comment: Thanks for the help @CBroe I tried using get_the_post_thumbnail but unfortunately that didn't help.

Comment: Did you actually pass it the proper post id, or did you let it fall back on the global post same way the_post_thumbnail does?

Comment: @Cbroe I tried using $post_id = get_the_ID(); and adding that into get the post thumbnail, but it appeared to just break and no images showed. You don't freelance by any chance do you? I really need to get this sorted, and with a function to avoid duplicates or I'm going to be very late delivering if I spend much more time on it LOL

Comment: _"but it appeared to just break and no images showed"_ - broke as in, getting you any errors ... or just no pictures, because you maybe just ignored what I said about the difference in the two function's behavior in the first comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without having your post type or taxonomy, it's difficult to test whether or not this works.  However, this should work.

As stated in the comments, you need to use get_the_ID() and I would also think that you need the `get_term_link` function rather than `get_category_link` as that would be for a `post` taxonomy `category` being the default WordPress category taxonomy.

```
$limit   = 999;
$counter = 0;
$cats    = get_terms(
    array(
        'taxonomy'   => 'categories',
        'hide_empty' => false,
    )
);

foreach ( $cats as $cat ) :
    if ( $counter < $limit ) {
        $args    = array(
            'posts_per_page'      => 1,
            'post_type'           => 'gallery',
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
            'tax_query'           => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
                    'terms'    => $cat->term_id,
                    'field'    => 'term_id',
                ),
            ),
        );
        $results = new WP_Query( $args );
        if ( $results->have_posts() ) {
            echo '<div class="col-md-3 category-list">';
            foreach ( $results->get_posts() as $the_post ) :
                echo '<a href="' . esc_url( get_term_link( $cat->term_id, 'categories' ) ) . '"><div class="cat-list-img">';
                $image = get_the_post_thumbnail( $the_post->ID, 'medium' ); // replace with whatever size you want here.
                echo $image;
                echo '<h5 class="cl-title">' . esc_attr( $cat->name ) . '</h5>';
                echo '</div></a>';
                echo '</div>';
            endforeach;
        }
    }

    $counter++;
endforeach;
```

Comment: Hey Howard, I did try essentially what you've changed there just in a slightly different way and it didn't work. I've just tried your code and it's not working, it shows images but they're all the same and it appears to just show the latest post in general rather than the latest post from that specific taxonomy.

Comment: I've changed how to use the loop.  see if this works.

Comment: Same thing, it's so frustrating I just don't get why it doesn't work...

Comment: I've updated again.  If you are getting more issues here... can you share at least one `var_dump` of `$the_post` - make sure it's querying the right stuff here.

Comment: That did the trick! So separating out the tax array is the way forward. Thanks so much man I've been stuck on this for some time. You couldn't point me in the right direction of potentially avoiding duplicate images could you? Some things are placed in multiple categories - no worries if not and I don't expect full code just a nudge in the right direction!

Comment: The potential duplicate images - would be another question, but you could explore using `get_post_thumbnail_id` - push results to an array, and check if each loop item's image id is in that array.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid duplicates, you can store the displayed post ID in an array and bypass if it appears again from other categories queries.

```
$limit      = 999;
$counter    = 0;
$cats = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'categories',
    'hide_empty' => false,
]);

$displayed_posts = array(); 

foreach ($cats as $cat):
    if ($counter < $limit) {
        $args  = array(
            'posts_per_page' => 1,
            'post_type'   => 'gallery',
            'taxonomy' => 'categories',
            'cat' => $cat->cat_ID,
            'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if ($posts) {
                echo '<div class="col-md-3 category-list">';
                while( have_posts() ) :
                    the_post();

                    $post_id = get_the_ID();
                    if ( in_array( $post_id, $displayed_posts ) ) {
                        continue;
                    }
                    $displayed_posts[] = $post_id;
                    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat->term_id) . '" ' . '><div class="cat-list-img">';
                    the_post_thumbnail();
                    echo '<h5 class="cl-title">' . $cat->name . '</h5>';
                    echo '</div></a>';
                    echo '</div>';
                endwhile;
        }
    }

$counter++;
endforeach;
```